# Use require() outside Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angularjs

I'm experimenting to get an Angular.js application working with Node.js.

Currently I have the code below in the file `MY-PROJECT/public/js/controllers.js`

```
function LoginController( $scope )
{
  // fetch waiters
  var Waiter = require( '../models/waiter.js' );
}
LoginController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

As you can see, I'm using require() to access a model file. But it seems like the require()-function is not accessible in this file / folder.

The error I get in the console when I visit the page is:

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

The reason for the error is most certainly because I directly include this controllers.js-file in my HTML-file with script-tags (so the require()-function from Node.js is not available).

Now my question is: how can I access a model-file (eg. from `MY-PROJECT/models/waiter.js`) in the controllers.js-file?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try adding script references to node.js and/or waiter.js in your html file like this example for waiter.js: <script src="MY-PROJECT/models/waiter.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it all wrong. Because I'm making a '*realtime-app*' (is that the correct name?) and using **Socket.io**, it works differently.

In the client-controller, I send a message to the server to request the data. The server fetches the data and send it back to the client.

So in the client I actually don't need to require the model, because I get the data in JSON-format from the server.

This is how I solved it, may be useful to others:

```
/**
* Login controller
*/
function LoginController( $scope, socket )
{    
    // listen to server when it sends you the cats
    socket.on( 'here-are-all-the-cats', function ( cats )
    {
        $scope.cats = cats;
    });

    // send message to the server, to request the waiters
    socket.emit( 'i-want-all-the-cats' );
}
WaiterController.$inject = [ '$scope', 'socket' ];
```

Note: I used 'cats' instead of 'waiters', just to make it more clear to others.

Comment: Should you install the listener before calling emit()?

Comment: I've tested this and it works when you put the listener after emit(); But you're right, probably best practice to put the listener before emit(); Updated!

Answer (score 1):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) looks like it has what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I've used RequireJS before for an entire, but how can I use it for just this one file?

Comment: I haven't used it, but the [API documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) looks helpful.

Comment: Thanks again, I've found another solution, see my answer below (or above?)